# How to use session.setAttribute("id", id) onclick a button in java servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets, servlet-3.0, httpsession

I want to store id in httpsession when a button is clicked so that I can use it in another servlet.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
<button>
   <a href = "\"http://localhost:8080/WhatASap/createConversation\""
            + "style=\"text-decoration:none\""
            + "onclick=\"session.setAttribute(\"ID\","+ ID + ")\">
        Chat 
   </a>
</button>
```

When I am clicking the button ID is not getting set in httpsession.

Comment: The onclick event happens in the browser - there is no HttpSession object.  Pass ID to the servlet which handles the href URL.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add variables into `HttpSession` from javascript. You'll have to do it in the servlet. Anything you write under `onclick` will be executed by the client browser's javascript engine which has no knowledge about your server.

---

As in your case, parse any variables to your `createConversation` servlet.

```
<a href='http://localhost:8080/WhatASap/createConversation/?ID=<%= ID %>'>
```

Next, in your servlet;

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("ID", request.getParameter("ID"));
```